# Android: painting over background picture in canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I try to hide a picture and show interactively its portions when user touches a screen. I tried numerous approaches like having background view that is overlapsed with views that I will make transparent which somehow worked. A final solution shall be a single custom view which will give me more painting flexibility.

Activity:

```
hiddenPicture.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture);
```

View:

```
init()
    eraserPaint = new Paint();
    eraserPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    // eraserPaint.setAlpha(0);
    eraserPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    veilPaint = new Paint();
    veilPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, w, h, veilPaint);
    canvas.drawOval(new RectF(20, 20, 220, 220), eraserPaint);
}
```

The problem is that the oval is black. I found tons of similar questions but I am too junior in Android to apply them to my case. What shall I do to erase oval in grey veil and show background picture? Thank you.

**Update:**

I found nice blog: http://www.41post.com/4794/programming/android-rendering-a-path-with-a-bitmap-fill

I recycled it to my code:

```
    fillBMP = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.picture);
    fillBmpShader = new BitmapShader(fillBMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    eraserPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    eraserPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    eraserPaint.setShader(fillBmpShader);
```

It seemed to work but the problem is that it does not scale the image used as brush. Is really the only solution to implement `onDraw()` this way:

1. Paint the picture
2. Paint the veil except uncovered parts

I worry about the performance. I do not want to paint complete screen after each user interaction. I would prefer to repaint only relevant parts. Is this even possible or am I over-optimizing already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to maintain and paint two bitmaps - one for background and second for veil with transparent hollows:

```
private void setupDrawing() {
    eraserPaint = new Paint();
    eraserPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    eraserPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    veilPaint = new Paint();
    veilPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}

// http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
    drawCanvas.drawRect(0, 0, w, h, veilPaint);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(fillBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        drawCanvas.drawCircle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 150, eraserPaint);
        invalidate();
    }
    return true;
}
```